# Reading document.links from an IFrame 

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, xss

EDIT:
Just a quick mention as to the nature of this program. The purpose of this program is for web inventory. Drawing different links and other content into a type of hierarchy. What I'm having trouble with is pulling a list of links from a webpage within an IFrame.

---

I get the feeling this one is gonna bite me hard. (other posts indicate relevance to xss and domain controls)

I'm just trying something with javascript and Iframes. Basically I have a panel with an IFrame inside that goes to whatever website you want it to. I'm trying to generate a list of links from the webpage within the Iframe. Its strictly read only.

Yet I keep coming up against the permission denied problem.

I understand this is there to stop cross site scripting attacks and the resolution seems to be to set the document domain to the host site. 
[JavaScript permission denied. How to allow cross domain scripting between trusted domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175006/javascript-permission-denied-how-to-allow-cross-domain-scripting-between-trusted)

However I dont think this will work if I'm trying to go from site to site.

Heres the code I have so far, pretty simple:

```
function getFrameLinks()
{
/* You can all ignore this. This is here because there is a frame within a frame. It should have no effect ont he program. Just start reading from 'contentFrameElement'*/


//ignore this
var functionFrameElem = document.getElementById("function-IFrame");
console.log("element by id parent frame ");
console.log(functionFrameElem);
var functionFrameData = functionFrameElem.contentDocument;
console.log("Element data");
console.log(functionFrameData);

//get the content and turn it into a doc
var contentFrameElem = functionFrameData.getElementById("content-Frame")
console.log(contentFrameElem);
var contentFrameData = contentFrameElem.contentDocument;
console.log(contentFrameData);

//get the links
//var contentFrameLinks = contentFrameData.links;
var contentFrameLinks = contentFrameData.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

---

Goal: OK so due to this being illegal and very similar to XSS. Perhaps someone could point out a solution as to how to locally store the document. I dont seem to have any problems accessing document.links with internal pages in the frame.

Possibly some sort of temp database of cache. The simpler the solution the better.

Comment: XSS fest ... that would be he joy of every hacker...

Comment: Not a hacker my friend. But I know that this is similar from reading other comments and threads.. edit: Is that your way of saying this in undoable? Even if its only reading data

Comment: Yes, reading data inside another frame of another domain is not allowed. You should use another technique to achieve your goal. But then, what is your goal?

Comment: @Deele Your suspicion is ill founded. I'm pretty sure it says it in the question but I'll edit it with specific information as to what I'm doing. edit: I've updated the question to drive away from the hacking or malicious intent notion. Its really only for web content and building a hierarchy using the links. A local store of page would be the goal now I guess.

Comment: @Deele Perhaps you have some techniques to achieve this?

Comment: Your goal is to count/get links inside some HTML, that you are not owning/resides on another page/host?

Comment: @Deele, yes that is the goal. Although remember that this page that I don't own is being held within a frame. Ruby on rails is being used server side if your curious.

Comment: @Overtone, wasn't referring to you about hacking .. just that if it was supported, the hackers would have a pretty easy job phishing people.. What i was referring-to is indeed that it is not possible through the browser.. Using server-side technologies is another thing, as you can read the whole remote-page and show it locally.

Comment: @Gaby aka G.Petrioli;  http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2432  This little gem seems to make that route an easy path to follow. I am curious as to how it would work in reference to this though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read it just for your self and in your browser, you can write a simple proxy with php in your server. the most simple code:

```
<?php /* proxy.php */ readfile($_GET['url']); ?>
```

now set your iframe src to your proxy file:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/proxy.php?url=http://www.google.com"
id="function-IFrame"></iframe>
```

now you can access the iframe content from your (local) server.
if you want set the url with a program remember to encode the url (urlencode in php or encodeURIComponent in js)

Comment: Server is using Rails but I'll look into some sort of alternative

Comment: I get whats going on here but is there any way to rip/scrape the page to a local store or temp folder/object that could be read locally?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bookmarklet you can run on any page (assuming the links are not in an iframe)

```
javascript:var x=function(){var lnks=document.links,list=[];for (var i=0,n=lnks.length;i<n;i++) {var href = lnks[i].href;  list.push(href)};if (list.length>0) { var w=window.open('','_blank');w.document.write(list.length+' links found<br/><ul><li>'+list.sort().join('</li><li>')+'</ul>');w.document.close()}};void(x());
```

the other way is for you (on Windows) to save your HTML with extension .HTA
Then you can grab whatever lives in the iFrame

Comment: The links I'm trying to grab are indeed in an IFrame. As is the initial page itself. Also I'd like to keep this as cross platform as possible. What I would ideally like is to save a temp version of the page to local store and read it from there.

Comment: I do not refer to YOUR iframe. The bookmarklet can read from any site that does not live in an iframe. If it DOES live in an iframe, copy the bookmarklet and change document.links to window.frames[0].document.links

Comment: @mplunigjan Apologies. The part of the script I indicated not to read was what I was referring to. The site does indeed live in an iframe in my application. However if you are referring to the target site (like the actual webpage navigating to it normally) then I apologize for the misunderstanding

Comment: That is what the bookmarklet does. It creates a new window with the list of links from the actual site you have in your browser window

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using the [YQL (*Yahoo Query Language*)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to retrieve filtered results from remote urls..

example of retrieving [all the links from the yahoo.com domain](http://y.ahoo.it/A3ovs)

Comment: This could be very very useful. Thank you

Comment: This answer is the ultimate broken link: [YQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Query_Language) itself has been retired.