# Change Links of A Website Within Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, href

I was wandering that if I could change the href attributes of all the links that are displayed within an IFrame. I had seen this system on many of the proxy site.

Please if anyone can provide me the code, I would be very grateful.

Comment: use javascript or jquery

Comment: cross domain operations are not allowed in browsers

Comment: From [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+document+links+iframe): http://stackoverflow.com/q/8890699/1741542, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6815535/1741542, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6688762/1741542

Answer (score 2):

Well actually you can, here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2XXxW/4/ as example how it works

```
var ifrmame = document.getElementById('iframe');
var a = ifrmame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0;i< a.length;i++) { 
    a[i].href = 'URL';
}
```

but iframes have to be the same origin, otherwise you cant access it for security reasons

Comment: well... fiddle just give and example how to work with content of iframe, no more no less. And it's nice to have it, as soon as you can quickly try it yourself, play with it, understand how it work... sadly  fiddle 404 have no links... and it have to be same origin ... that's why

Comment: sory. my bad :) thre are links, just noticed it have element with ID="body"... and chrome links it as id :) updated example