# Get innertext/innerHTML from another domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how would I do if I wanted to get the content/text from another website? 
For example if I wanted to get the latest stock price or something from an website.

Is it possible to do something like this in javascript, but pull from an external domain.

```
var textAlr
textAlr = document.getElementById("thedivid").innerHTML

function alertText(){
window.alert(textAlr); 

}
```

thanks in advance (:

Comment: You can use API for this.

Comment: Same Origin Policy, learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a touchy thing and it's generally forbidden. It call ed a cross domain error. If you have permission to take the content, you see about setting that up here:
[JavaScript permission denied. How to allow cross domain scripting between trusted domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175006/javascript-permission-denied-how-to-allow-cross-domain-scripting-between-truste)

otherwise, the best way to do it is to use cUrl from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the other domain is set up. If it allows access from an external domain you can do...

```
$.get('http://some-other-domain.com/something.html', function(html){
  var text = $(html).find('#thedivid').html();
  alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use load() function in jquery may help you solve this problem:

```
$('#the_target_div').load("url.html #thedivid", function() {
  // stuff to do when content is ready
});
```