# Access jQuery from iframe with another domain

Tags: jquery, iframe, cors

Okay, I have a big problem today. I've just created a site with an iframe with `src="somedomain.com/somepage.html"`, but I don't know the way to access the jQuery, which the `somepage.html` includes. I know of CORS, but I can also run functions in iframe with parent page. So is there any way to run jQuery object functions inside the iframe from parent page?

*Note: I can't chnage content of somepage.html.*

---

**I tried the following:**

```
mainIframe.contentWindow.$
```

but the console gave an error:

> Error: Permission denied to access property "$"

It is really possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not allowed to access a frame from another domain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175006/javascript-permission-denied-how-to-allow-cross-domain-scripting-between-truste

Comment: Can you add anything at all to the parent page?  A snip of javascript perhaps?  If no, then you're stuck.  Allowing the document inside the iframe to modify the parent document poses security concerns, which is why it's not allowed.

Comment: @MartyMulligan I can change whatever I want to in parent page, but I can't in iframe. I don't know if I understand right. I don't want to modify parent page from iframe, but I want to access jQuery from parent page :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  If you have any access at all to the frame contents (even one time) you can communicate between iframes by posting / intercepting "message" events.  Otherwise, yeah like the accepted answer says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access a child frame from a different domain. It's a security reason. If you could access data inside a child frame that is in a different domain, it would be easy enough to simulate fake pages.

Comment: Great, but what about forms etc?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to access anything in a child frame that is in a different domain. And I think that it's great that way. Security concerns.

Comment: Well, it seems I have no choice, I'll use PHP's http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php :) Thanks anyway...

Comment: Although you can't directly access the child frame, you can send data from the child frame to the parent page using [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).